# Ideas on how my object became hollow

Tags: modifiers

I started out with a simple cube and edited the vertices to make it look like so...

[image]

I think somewhere along the way I did something to make the object hollow, because when I cut an object out of it (Boolean Modifier -> Difference), you can see the insides (as follows)...

[image]

Is there a way to add the "fill" back to it so that it's solid?

[Blender Source File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By236p5CTnzhY2c3MGYtQmd1SzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering my own question, but in hopes it might help someone else...

1. Create a giant cube that surrounds all edges of your problem hollow object.
2. Add a Boolean + Intersect modifier to the cube with the target object as your hollow object.
3. Apply the modifier and delete the old hollow object, and now
   you should have a filled object on the new "cube".